# Install and configure Rpy2 on opensuse

Tags: python, r, opensuse, rpy2

I'm try to install R module for python(rpy) on opensuse, however after execute command "sudo  easy_install rpy2, I get this error msgs:

"Setup script exited with Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH."

Someone could help?

thanks
jayron

Answer (score 3):

If you use Ubuntu's package management, it should pull in all the dependencies, including R:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rpy2
```